# don't recieve full length sms from sms gateway, recieved sms skip the string after space

Tags: php, sms-gateway

```
'&message=Hi Your 6 digit OTP code is :-'.$otp_code.'
```

Hi All, I have a problem I am passing above string as message a message in query string

URL is given by sms gateway company is

```
http://sms.w3karigar.com/http-api.php?username=enterusername&password=enterpassword&senderid=6char-senderid&route=1&number=enternumber&message=Hi Your 6 digit OTP code is :-'.$otp_code.'
```

received message contain only Hi.

when I pass the query string like -

```
http://sms.w3karigar.com/http-api.php?username=enterusername&password=enterpassword&senderid=6char-senderid&route=1&number=enternumber&message=HiYour6digitOTPcodeis'.$otp_code.'
```

then I received full length SMS.
can anyone help me thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Use `php` function `urlencode()` to create urls

```
urlencode ("Hi Your 6 digit OTP code is :-".$otp_code)
```

Comment: yes off course but currently I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

**The regular expression should be able to help you**

```js
$url = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
preg_match('/message=(.*?)($|&)/is', $url, $message);
var_dump($message[1]);EXIT;
```

---

*usually we encode request url before we use it:*

```js
Hi Your 6 digit OTP code is :-'.$otp_code.'
```

to

```js
Hi%20Your%206%20digit%20OTP%20code%20is%20:-%27.$otp_code.%27
```